# Can't make Ext GWT 3.0 run

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am having a problem running a Ext GWT 3.0 with GWT (version 2.4). I tried making a Web Application Project from plugin but the I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find 'com/extjs/gxt/ui/GXT.gwt.xml' on your classpath;
```

When I change the `gxt.jar` to lower version: gxt-2.2.5 the demo application runs.

Anyone have experience the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module name changed from 2.2 to 3.0. Instead of inheriting the com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT module, inherit com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT in your module file.

```
<inherits name="com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT" />
```

This packaging has changed, along with the packaging of all of the classes, allowing you to have both jars on the classpath at once, and even inherited at once. This was done in part because of the large number of changes from 2.2 to 3.0.